# Regex remove string in text

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to remove

```
[PRODUCT ID=123]
```

from text

```
Some random dummy [PRODUCT ID=123] text just for example [PRODUCT ID=321]
```

Where ID (after the = sign) can be any number (integer).

I've tried with PHP

`preg_match_all("|[[^]]+](.*)[]/[^]]+]|U", $text, $out);`

but it doesn't work as I thought it will so I'm trying with regex but currently I'm lost and I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: do you need to remove just bracketed PRODUCT ID text, or **ANYTHING** in `[]` pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/\[PRODUCT ID=(\d*)\]/", '', 'Some random dummy [PRODUCT ID=123] text just for example [PRODUCT ID=321]');
```

Comment: Or, if you want a generic version: `\[(?:\w+\s\w+=\d+)\]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str = 'Some random dummy [PRODUCT ID=123]text just for example [PRODUCT ID=321]';
preg_replace('/\[PRODUCT ID=.*?\]/', '', $str);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ' ads [PRODUCT ID=123] [PRODUCT ID=4124124321] asd \ a sda s';
$a = preg_replace("~(\[PRODUCT ID=)([0-9]*)(\])~", "", $a);
echo $a;
// ads asd \ a sda s
```